# How to add tags to to Lamda function's network interface using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

When a lambda function is created and then attach to a VPC it auto creates a Network Interface.
I'm trying to find a way to attach tags to the created network interface using terraform.

I found the following method to attach tags to network interface:

```
 resource "aws_nat_gateway" "public_subnet" {
   subnet_id     = var.ip
 }

 resource "aws_ec2_tag" "nat_gateway_network_interface" {
   for_each = local.tags
   resource_id = aws_nat_gateway.public_subnet.network_interface_id
   key         = each.key
   value       = each.value
 }
```

I suspect what I'm looking for is a way to acquire the lamda function network interface id. Any idea how I can do this in Terraform ?

Comment: I don't know of any way (and would be interested to learn of one). But one thing to be aware of is that multiple Lambdas can share a network interface.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the AWS Documentation goes, this information is not accessible. Network Interfaces can be recycled or reused based on lot of factors. So if something is not accessible then pretty sure it is not a issue with Terraform.

If you want to do it anyway then look at this 2 years old thread
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/fhjwu5/can_i_get_the_network_interface_id_for_a_lambda/

From this AWS Article (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-eni-find-delete/) you can run a script and get the ENIs. But it kills the idea of doing it easily and repetitively via Terraform though.